# Run two CSS animation classes delay between two but infinite

Tags: css, button, css-animations

I want to run two CSS animation on the button but with a delay b/w two but running then infinitely and pausing it for few seconds then repeating it again.

Shake for 3 seconds and just after finishing of shake Pulse animation gonna start up for 2 seconds and then pausing both for 5 seconds now repeat again.

```
 .single_add_to_cart_button {
animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both,
pulse 2s infinite;
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
backface-visibility: hidden;
perspective: 1000px;
animation-duration: 6s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {0%{-webkit-transform:scale(.98);transform:scale(.98)}70%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1)}to{-webkit-transform:scale(.98);transform:scale(.98)}}@keyframes pulse{0%{-webkit-transform:scale(.98);transform:scale(.98)}70%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1)}to{-webkit-transform:scale(.98);transform:scale(.98)}}

@keyframes shake{from,16%,to{-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}1.6%,4.8%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(-1px,0,0);transform:translate3d(-1px,0,0)}8%,11.2%,14.4%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(-4px,0,0);transform:translate3d(-4px,0,0)}9.6%,12.8%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(4px,0,0);transform:translate3d(4px,0,0)}3.2%,6.4%{-webkit-transform:translate3d(2px,0,0);transform:translate3d(2px,0,0)}}

<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt disabled wc-variation-selection-needed">YES,I WANT IT NOW</button>
```

Comment: Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: I added the css and html code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play different css animations one after another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343754/how-to-play-different-css-animations-one-after-another)